# First steps in jclouds

Tags: java, post, openstack, openstack-nova, jclouds

I'm having some problems when I try to connect with my openstack. I'm using jclouds and this is my code:

```
    context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("openstack-nova")
            .endpoint("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/v2.0/")
            .credentials("tenantname:username", "password")
            .modules(ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new SLF4JLoggingModule(), new   SshjSshClientModule()))
            .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);

    service = context.getComputeService();

    for(ComputeMetadata node: service.listNodes()) {
        System.out.println("NODE: " + node.getId());
    }
```

But always it return the following error:

```
 DEBUG [org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod] [main] >> invoking    AuthenticationApi.authenticateWithTenantNameAndCredentials
 DEBUG [org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService] [main] Sending request -1502473400: POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1
 ERROR [org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService] [main] Command not considered safe to retry because request method is POST: [method=org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.AuthenticationApi.public abstract org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.domain.Access org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.AuthenticationApi.authenticateWithTenantNameAndCredentials(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.domain.PasswordCredentials)[tenantname, PasswordCredentials{username=username, password=*****}], request=POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1]
```

I'm developing in eclipse and Intellij IDEA. I've been reviewing the proxy configuration, but everything is normal.

Please, can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good, but if you need to go through a proxy you may need to configure the proxy properties in jclouds. Something like the following, with the right values for your proxy:

```
Properties overrides = new Properties();
overrides.setProperty(Constants.PROPERTY_PROXY_HOST, "localhost");
overrides.setProperty(Constants.PROPERTY_PROXY_PORT, "8888");
```

You can pass the properties to the `overrides` method of the ContextBuilder.

You can also enable the `jclouds.wire` logs to see every request and response that are being sent. This will show the exact network error or the one returned by your OpenStack installation. Have a look at: http://jclouds.apache.org/reference/logging/

Comment: Thanks you!! Your answer is perfect, I've used it in my code and it's working well! Thanks a lot!!